# Importing Materializecss from CDN and getting select dropdown to work in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, dropdown, materialize

I have a ReactJS project where i include [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) from its CDN:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

My problem is that i want to initialize a select element. I've searched for similar questions, all importing the `M` function from `node_modules` and then invoking it in `componentDidMount()`.

I want to avoid `npm install materialize-css@next` and just include the package from the `CDN`.

I tried `window.M.AutoInit()`, no error occurred but it is not even creating a dropdown. How to invoke `M.AutoInit()`?

Comment: Why you want to avoid npm install?

Comment: I just want to check if there is a way that i can access Objects from libraries included with CDN.

Comment: But the way React or node is, don't you think it'll be better to have the modules in package.json?  I think it'll be good in case of deployment also.

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke, indeed its a better way and that was my final implementation, but I would like to know if there is another way, the CDN one.

Comment: I'll check for you if it is possible or not till then you can check this website for materialize in react - https://reactize.herokuapp.com

Comment: Thank you very much, great work done from you on that webpage

Answer (score 1):

I think that i found the answer on my question.

On constructor you have to add `this.M = window.M`:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    ...
    this.M = window.M;
    ...
  }
```

So after that using `this.M.AutoInit()` outside constructor should work!

Comment: I tried but I wasn't able to get the M, this is really good! +1